# What firstly comes when adjective and adverb put together in a meaning?

Tags: word-order

Which one is right?

> Have a lovely nice day

or

> Have a nice lovely day

Answer (score 1):

Those are both adjectives, with about the same meaning. For an ordinary greeting, you should use just one.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your confusion. When you add -ly to an adjective, it makes an adverb, however lovely is unusual: it is an adjective, not an adverb. There are other -ly adjectives, for example friendly, kindly, likely, lively, manly, and timely.

To answer your question about word order for adjectives and adverbs, it is important to note that only certain sorts of adverbs can be applied to adjectives. Adverbs of degree, like slightly, very, extremely, etc. can be used this way, and they always go before the adjective.

> Have a very good day

[This article](https://www.talkenglish.com/speaking/lessondetails.aspx?ALID=4211) covers other types of adverb that can be used to modity adjectives.

Comment: No, *love* is only ever a verb or a noun, not an adjective. So we're just talking about the correct ordering of two adjectives here.

Comment: @tchrist. You are, of course, right. I have updated my answer.